# Blender 2.8 lattice doesn't work (MacOS)

Tags: modifiers, lattice

Lattice added. The model is inside. In the modifier settings the lattice is connected. But the deformation does not change anything.

[image]

Comment: Hard to tell from your random screenshot, but is your mesh actually subdivided?

Comment: @metaphor_set Thank you. I misunderstood the work of the lattice! Subdivide solved the problem!